# How do I execute an Angular2 v2.1+ ES5 only app without using a builder (Webpack/Gulp)?

Tags: angular

I don't have the option to install or run any builders, bundlers, or SystemJS. I want to use Angular2 v2.1+, but their documentation is very skim when discussing ES5 only apps that are "self executing".

The angular team, during the alpha/beta phases made available angular-all.umd.js or angular2.sfx.dev.js files in order to accomplish this, but are completely missing in anything 2.0+ repos.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't use nmp directly either. Will have to download any necessary files and self host.